# How to do pattern matching in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, pattern-matching, racket

Has anyone an idea how to make pattern matching in Scheme with this two (?x lives-in ?city) (john lives-in new-york) ?

I've tried using match-define, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: What Scheme are you working with? Chicken, Racket, etc?

Answer (score 10):

I guess you meant *pattern* matching. For the general solution to this problem, think about implementing the [Unification Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29#Unification_in_logic_programming), there's a complete working solution described in [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-29.html#%_sec_4.4). Alternatively, consider embedding [miniKANREN](http://kanren.sourceforge.net/#mini) in your code, it's a simple logic programming system that works with Scheme.

Now, for a simpler match you can use Racket's [Pattern Matching](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) abilities. For the example in the question:

```
(define expression '(john lives-in new-york))

(match expression
  [(list ?x 'lives-in ?city) (list ?x ?city)]
  [_ #f])

=> '(john new-york)
```

The above will match a given expression against the `(?x lives-in ?city)` pattern, returning a list with the matched values for `?x` and `?city`, or `#f` if no match was found.

Comment: I have one a question. Is scheme Pattern Matching implemented using unification algorithm? For me, scheme Pattern Matching is really powerful and I would like to understand the formal aspects of it.